# displaying \rule in title page

Tags: titles, rules

I have the following test document.  I want to use `\noindent\rule{19cm}{5pt}`
after the title and `\noindent\rule{19cm}{3pt}` after the author name.

But the two rules are being displayed in another page.

```latex
    \documentclass[12pt]{book}
    
    \usepackage{geometry}
    \geometry{ paperheight=21cm, paperwidth=21cm, left=8mm, right=8mm,
      top=21mm, bottom=8mm}
    
    \usepackage{type1cm}
    \makeatletter
    \renewcommand\normalsize{%
       \@setfontsize\normalsize{16pt}{16pt}
       \abovedisplayskip 10\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus5\p@
       \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus3\p@
       \belowdisplayshortskip 6\p@ \@plus3\p@ \@minus3\p@
       \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
       \let\@listi\@listI}
    \makeatother
    
    \begin{document}
    \normalsize
    
    \begin{titlepage}
      \begin{flushleft}
        \title{Fredholm Integral Transforms}
      \end{flushleft}
     
      \noindent\rule{19cm}{5pt}
      \noindent\rule{19cm}{3pt}
      \date{\today}
      
      \begin{flushleft}
       \author{An Author}
       \noindent\rule{19cm}{3pt}
      \end{flushleft}
      
    \end{titlepage}
    
    \maketitle
    
    \chapter{Introduction}
    
    Hello
    
    \end{document}
```

Comment: you probably want to delete `\maketitle` as you are not using `\author`, `\title` but just setting `titlepage` directly. Also `\@setfontsize\normalsize{16pt}{16pt}`  is very tight setting, 16pt font on 16pt baseline?

Comment: I have copied the `\@setfontsize\normalsize{16pt}{16pt}` because I wanted a larger font that the default for book.  What do the two 16pt values refer to?

Comment: `\maketitle` is needed, otherwise the title page is not displayed.  But I cannot get the left alignment.

Comment: no that is not how it works, `titlepage` typesets directly, it is an alternative to `\maketitle`. If you use the `titlepage` option then `\maketitle` is defined in terms of `titlepage` but even then it never uses a `titlepage` that appears in your documnt body.

Comment: note you also have two rules side by side not oe above the other: `Overfull \hbox (532.70267pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 26--29`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use commands such as `\author` and `\title` that save data to be used by `\maketitle` *or* use `titlepage` to set content directly. You are doing both, so setting a title page with just the rules, then using `\author` wihin that which saves the data for `\maketitle`.

[image]

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{book}
    
    \usepackage{geometry}
    \geometry{ paperheight=21cm, paperwidth=21cm, left=8mm, right=8mm,
      top=21mm, bottom=8mm}
    
    \usepackage{type1cm}
    \makeatletter
    \renewcommand\normalsize{%
       \@setfontsize\normalsize{16pt}{18pt}%
       \abovedisplayskip 10\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus5\p@
       \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus3\p@
       \belowdisplayshortskip 6\p@ \@plus3\p@ \@minus3\p@
       \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
       \let\@listi\@listI}
    \makeatother
    
    \begin{document}
    \normalsize
    
    \begin{titlepage}
      \begin{flushleft}
        Fredholm Integral Transforms
      
     
      \rule{19cm}{5pt}

      \rule{19cm}{3pt}
      
       \today
      

       An Author

       \rule{19cm}{3pt}
      \end{flushleft}
      
    \end{titlepage}
    
 
    
    \chapter{Introduction}
    
    Hello
    
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so very much.  Want to push the author and successive rule at the bottom of the page.